# Замена чисел в строке на двоичные

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Задача: на входе дана строка, в которой встречаются разные числа и символы. Надо преобразовать все числа в строке в двоичную систему, а символы оставить на месте. Использовать си-строки. Написал код, а он какой-то китайский выдает, помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char* convertToBinary(int y) {
    char* a = new char[4];
    int i = 0;
    while (y > 0) {
        if (y % 2 == 0)
            a[i] = '0';
        else
            a[i] = '1';
        y /= 2;
        i += 1;
    }
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    char* s = new char;
    
    int i, k = 1, x = 0;
    cin >> s;
    int len = strlen(s);
    char* b = new char[len];
    i = strlen(s) - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            x += (s[i] - '0') * k;
            k *= 10;
        }
        else if (s[i + 1] >= '0' && s[i + 1] <= '9') {
            const char* z = convertToBinary(x);
            strcat(b, z);
            b[strlen(b)] = s[i];
            x = 0;
            k = 1;
        }
        else {
            b += s[i];
        }
        i--;
    }
    if (x != 0) {
        const char* z = convertToBinary(x);
        strcat(b, z);
        
    }
    for (int j = strlen(b) - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        cout << b[j];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А "символы" - это английские или русские буквы? а то ведь есть еще кодировка, и по умолчанию она UTF-8

Comment: Символы - это латинские буквы, #, *, &.....

Comment: Ваша программа - это одна большая утечка памяти. Где входная строка? s - ? - так это просто указатель на один символ. Где удаление динамически выделенной памяти? Если можно использовать `strlen()`, то может можно использовать и стандартные функции для преобразования строки в число? Что по-Вашему означает выражение `b += s[i]`?

Comment: да, я пока еще не озаботился вопросом утечки памяти, потому что оно принципиально не работает...  b += s[i] должно записывать к массиву b элемент s[i] , но насколько я понял, это так не работает, к сожалению

Comment: Начните с ввода строки. Вместо вот этого `char* s = new char;` задайте нормальный размер строке, которого должно хватить для задачи. И здесь можно использовать и статический массив, пусть даже на 10000 элементов. Раз просили использовать Си-строки, то я бы для ввода использовал `fgets()`, поскольку в нем можно задать максимальный размер строки (это чтобы не выйти за пределы массива), ну или getline().